# \movie autostart does not work in beamer

Tags: beamer, presentations, movie15, video

I want to include a video in my beamer presentation by \movie and need that starts automatically when the slide opens. There is an autostart option but does not work. I am reading the pdf by pymress on Windows and I can not use \includemedia.
This is the code that I'm using:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node [anchor=south, inner sep=22pt] at (current page.south) {
      \movie[
       width=0.47\linewidth,
       height=0.31\linewidth, 
       autostart,
       poster,
       showcontrols
  ]{}{file.mp4}
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi, welcome. `movie15` is obsolete look at `media9` from the same maintener (AlexG): https://ctan.org/pkg/media9